# Ionic/Angular - store content of an asynchronous http.get request in a variable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, promise, get

I try to get the content of a URL. I use the Promise since I'm in an asynchronous mode.
With the *function(results)* I can get all I want in the *test123* variable. But when I try to store that result in the *test1234* variable to use it outside the function it does not work. To be more precise the content of *test1234* becomes undefined..
How could I do to make the test1234 variable filled with the content of that http.get ?

Here is the snippet :

```
     this.http.get(URL2).toPromise().then(
                function(results) {
                 var test123 = results['features'][0]['properties']['gid']; // works
                 this.test1234 = test123;
                 console.log(this.test1234); // doesn't work, it's "undefined"
                },
                //error function
                function(err) {
                  //handle error
                }
  );
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like `test123` is really undefined, I'd check this part `results['features'][0]['properties']['gid']`. Also why don't you use Observables?

Comment: Why are you using promises in Angular? How do you know that thing works? Anyway, use arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use promises (you need to use arrow function)

```
this.http
  .get(URL2)
  .toPromise()
  .then(
    (results) => {
      this.test1234 = results['features'][0]['properties']['gid'];
    },
    (err) => {}
  );
```

But I suggest you use observables

```js
this.http.get(URL2).subscribe((results) => {
  this.test1234 = results['features'][0]['properties']['gid'];
});
```

Comment: OK I forgot the use of the narrow fonction.. by using it it indeed works.. Thank you very much ! Could you just tell me why it would be better to use Observables ?

Comment: One good argument would be because that's exactly what HttpClient is returning. Other than that, RxJS is very powerful, it would take a while to explain everything. Also, toPromise is about to be deprecated https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks for the precisions, I will check your link !